# Python variable scope in if-statements

Tags: python

In Python, are variable scopes inside if-statements visible outside of the if-statement? (coming from a Java background, so find this a bit odd)

In the following case, name is first defined inside the if-block but the variable is visible outside of the if-block as well. I was expecting an error to occur but 'joe' gets printed.

```
if 1==1:
    name = 'joe'
print(name)
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`if` statements don't define a scope in Python.

Neither do loops, `with` statements, `try` / `except`, etc.

Only modules, functions and classes define scopes.

See [Python Scopes and Namespaces](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) in the Python Tutorial.

Comment: Oh... sorry.. I was wrong about that.

Comment: @Owen you're thinking of the `nonlocal` keyword I assume, which doesn't define a scope, just adds a syntax for referring to an enclosing but non-global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Python, variable scopes inside if-statements are visible outside of the if-statement.
Two related questions gave an interestion discussion:

[Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

and

[Python variable scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question)

Answer (score 1):

All python variables used in a function live in the function level scope. (ignoring global and closure variables)

It is useful in case like this:

```
if foo.contains('bar'):
   value = 2 + foo.count('b')
else:
   value = 0
```

That way I don't have to declare the variable before the if statement.

Comment: Your first line is incorrect. If I define a variable in a class definition it's not in the global scope, a closure, or function level scope.

Comment: @agf - classes don't define a new scope — I can't access class variables from a method without qualification (ie. I need `Class.thing` or `self.thing`, not just `thing`). They have their own namespace, though.

Comment: @agf - actually, now that I think about it, I guess you can access class variables from the class definition *outside of methods*, so I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: @afg, stuff you create in a class definition is stored in the local scope just like when you are executing a function. That scope later becomes the class dictionary. But that's probably beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: @Winston I understand that either is the local scope, but read the first line prior to the edit -- he specifically said "all [local] Python variables live in the function level scope". That's incorrect; there is another statement that defines a local scope other than a function definition -- a class definition.

Comment: @agf, yes. That's why I edited. I didn't think of classes originally, because I don't typically think of those as variables.