# "raise" at the end of a python function outside "try" or "except" block

Tags: python, python-2.7

What does `raise` do, if it's not inside a `try` or `except` clause, but simply as the last statement in the function?

```
def foo(self):
    try:
        # some code that raises an exception
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    # notice that the "raise" is outside
    raise
```

This example prints 1 but not 2 so it must be that the last `raise` statement simply raises the last thrown exception.

```
def foo():
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    print 1
    raise
    print 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Any official documentation for this type of usage pattern?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957829/how-to-use-raise-keyword-in-python

Comment: *"it must be that the last raise statement simply raises the last thrown exception"* - yes, exactly. *"Any official documentation for this type of usage pattern?"* - see [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement): *"If no expressions are present, `raise` re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope. If no exception is active in the current scope, a `TypeError` exception is raised..."*

Comment: hi jonrsharpe, so try and except do not create new scopes? If so, then you have answered my question!

Comment: @gli no, that's still the Local scope - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7382643/3001761

Comment: @gli Did you see this in actual code? Or is this just something you thought of? If the former, then I'd be curious to see what the function that calls it looks like.

Comment: Be *careful* using `raise` in this way in python 2 if you're using nested exception handlers - there's a nasty bit of behavior related to scoping rules that can be very surprising.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707530/previous-error-being-masked-by-current-exception-context

Answer (score 7):

As [Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632181/2216621) said,

> A bare `raise` statement re-raises the last caught exception.

It doesn't matter whether this is happening in a try-except block or not. If there has been a caught exception, then calling `raise` will re-raise that exception. Otherwise, Python will complain that the previously caught exception is `None` and raise a `TypeError` because `None` is not something that can actually be raised.

As [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632548/2216621) said, it doesn't seem to make sense to do this except in an error-handling function. Personally I'd say that it doesn't even belong in an error-handling function, as the `raise` should still be in the `except` clause. Someone could use this in an attempt to execute code whether or not an error occurs, but a `finally` clause is the proper way to do that. Another possibility would be using this as a way to determine if an error occurred while executing the function, but there are much better ways to do that (such as returning an extra value that indicates if/where an error occurred).

Comment: A quick clarification - it does make sense if the function is used for error handling.

Comment: @tdelaney Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Let's say you have a list of parsers that you want to try in order until one returns a value instead of raising an error. Doing a final `raise` at the end of such a function is quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

A bare `raise` statement re-raises the last caught exception. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Comment: except the OP is asking about a bare raise outside of an exception - which is invalid and causes a TypeError exception.

Comment: I don't think it's invalid. I just ran an example and it did not throw a TypeError exception.

Comment: It will `raise TypeError` if there's no error to re-raise.

Answer (score 3):

A Bare raise reraises the current exception. This usually makes no sense at the end of a function, unless the function is called in an exception:

By itself, the raise is invalid and python throws its own exception

```
>>> def x():
...     raise
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in x
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
```

But if called within an exception block, it acts sanely

```
>>> try:
...     int('a')
... except:
...     x()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
>>>
```

**EDIT**

This might be a perfectly reasonable thing to do if the function is attempting some sort of recovery. The function could fix what's broken, log a message, trigger the fire extinguishers, etc... and `raise` if it still thinks the system is in error.

Answer (score 2):

From this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) we can read:

> If no expressions are present, raise re-raises the last exception that
>   was active in the current scope. If no exception is active in the
>   current scope, a TypeError exception is raised indicating that this is
>   an error (if running under IDLE, a Queue.Empty exception is raised
>   instead).

This means that, in the case of your code, if no exception occurs within the `try ... except` block, then you are forcing the program to raise a [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError) exception to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this where I needed to raise a previously caught exception outside the try/except block if my function didn't return a value. I did a bit of looking around in the `sys` and `traceback` modules, but couldn't find a good method to do this, so I just ended up storing the exception outside the block.

```py
def foo():
    caught = None

    try:
        raise Exception
    except Exception as e:
        caught = e
        pass

    raise caught


f = foo()
```

#### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 13, in <module>
  line 10, in foo
  line 5, in foo
Exception
```

Clearly this isn't useful in the above example, but it's pretty useful if you need to try something quite a few times in a loop and re-raise. My specific need was for an HTTP request retry mechanism.

```py
import time

def foo(key):
    caught = None
    
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        try:
            return d[key]
        except KeyError as e:
            caught = e
            print(i)
            time.sleep(i)
            continue

    raise caught

d = {"bar": "baz"}

f = foo(key="baz")
```

#### Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 19, in <module>
  line 15, in foo
  line 8, in foo
KeyError: 'baz'
```

Comment: This is the answer I thought would work with my use case, and I swear it's worked for me in the past. With Python 3.9.15 now though, if I assign the error `e` to another variable inside of my Except statement, Python completely skipped entering the Except block as if I didn't have a try/except at all. Bizarre!

Comment: Just tried this again, works perfectly in Python 3.10.10. You've got a bug in your code.

Comment: It's super strange. Always worked for me before. Get this: all I had to do was comment out the line where I assigned the error variable within the except block, and my except worked just fine. Put the line back, completely skips except block and errors out as if there was no try/except at all.